# Installing a wiki on Snow Leopard

Tags: apache-http-server, macos, twiki

I want to install twiki on my mac and serve it from ~/Sites/. Because the wiki has code to be run, I have to modify the user and group of wiki's files and directories, but I'm not sure about the following:

1) It is secure to change the user and group of the directory to the web server's group? If not, what can I do having into account that I'll not put 777 permissions on those files?
2) How are named apache and web user groups?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should look into foswiki, the open source fork of twiki (fully compatible)

The Foswiki project certainly seems to be more lively than twiki. They also have a page on the osx install - perhaps it works for you: http://foswiki.org/Support/FoswikiOnMacOSXLeopard